# Does GCC support long long int?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does GCC support:

```
long long int
```

which would be a 64-bit integer?

Also, is `long long int` part of the standard?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've never played with 64 bit data before and I'm freaking lazy tonight.

Comment: Note that in a C99 environment, you should use `int64_t` in `<stdint.h>` for a portable 64-bit integer.  If you're not in a C99 environment, `long long` is your best bet, but it's not actually guaranteed to be 64 bits wide.

Comment: ST: Well, it *is* guaranteed to be *at least* 64-bits wide, so he shouldn't worry that somewhere out there it's < 64. Not in a conforming implementation, anyway.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes GCC does support `long long int`, which is a part of C99 standard.

The standard does not mandate its size in bits, but required values of `LLONG_MIN` and `LLONG_MAX` in `<limits.h>` imply it's *at least* 64-bit (*exact* 64-bit wide integer types are `int64_t`/`uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`).

1. `LLONG_MIN` must be at most `-9223372036854775807`
2. `LLONG_MAX` must be at least `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Just to add.. In windows its equivalent would be _int64

Comment: Actually, to be strict, it is the equivalent of int64_t from <stdint.h> (which is C99 too).

Comment: @vpram86 "In windows its equivalent would be _int64" On my window's compiler it is `int64_t/uint64_t`.  Perhaps you mean "In [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx) its equivalent would be `__int64`" ?

Answer (score 13):

`long long int` is a part of the C99 standard, and I know GCC supports it. [And now I can prove it.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html)

Answer (score 9):

On my 32-bit machine,

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long int));
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc` prints 8 (8 bytes * 8 bits/byte = 64 bits).

Comment: `size_t` format strings should use `"%zu"` not `"%d"` (likewise, `ssize_t` must use `"%zd"`). This is a problem on 64-bit platforms, where size_t is often a 64-bit type, while int can still be 32-bit.

Comment: sizeof(char)==1 by definition but that is allowed to be >= one byte. So 64 bit types are allowed to have sizef(t)==1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `long long` is part of C99, as well as `long long` constants (`10222333444555LL`) and a few support elements. (`LLONG_MAX`, `llrint(d)`, `llround(d)`, some others.)  And gcc has implemented it for some time now.

Answer (score 5):

In order to print long long int variables:

```
long long int lli = 100000000;

printf("%lld\n", lli);
```

Answer (score 5):

long longs are well supported, and have been for a long long time [sorry].  As I understand it, this should have been 128 bit on 64-bit platforms, but for compatibility/portability reasons in GCC, has standardised on a 64-bit width.

See also: (u)int128_t, and this [discussion on GCC's 128-bit integer support](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2005-August/006412.html)

Comment: "this should have been 128 bit on 64-bit platforms": care to support this affirmation in any way?

Comment: I did say, "as I understand it".  I can support the idea only in that, as wikipedia says, "The term word is used for a small group of bits which are handled simultaneously by processors of a particular architecture. The size of a word is thus CPU-specific."  So logically, a long long word would be longer on an wider arch.  However, from the same wikipedia page, the de facto standard does seem to be that long long is 64-bit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 2):

I believe that usually an `unsigned long long` is the traditional representation of a 64-bit integer. I'm assuming `long long int` would work too, but I've never personally seen any 64-bit vars declared that way before.

Comment: `long long int` is just a signed 64-bit (or more) integer. Nothing particularly unusual about it.