# Hexadecimal to Hexatridecimal in c++

Tags: c++, math, numbers, hex

I am attempting to convert base 16 to base 36. I'm taking md5 hashes and making them have all 0-9a-z.

I searched around and didn't find anything good. Any suggestions for converting hexadecimal to hexatridecimal in c++? Do you guys know any good libraries for doing it?

Comment: i don't understand the question :$

Comment: How do I convert convert 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 from base 16 to base 36 in C++?

Comment: I will post C++ code later which does what you want, but in the meantime, this post is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419606/compress-21-alphanumeric-characters-in-to-16-bytes

Comment: The Any Base Calculator (http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ewe.radixcalculator) in the Android Play Market can do that.  It can be used to convert between base 16 and base 36.  It is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the tricky part you're struggling with is the conversion to Rad36, not getting a integral value from a hex number represented as a string.  So, here is a function which takes an `unsigned __int64`, converts it to [Radix 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36), and returns a string with the converted value.

```
string rad36(unsigned __int64 v)
{
    string retval;
    while( v > 0 )
    {
        unsigned m = v%36;
        if( m <= 9 )
            retval.insert(0,1,'0'+m);
        else
            retval.insert(0,1,'A'+m-10);
        v /= 36;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: You may want to make it return the remainder so that calls to `rad36` can be chained.

Comment: @Alexandre C.:  Probably a good idea.  I didn't need this in my application, so I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error "error: expected ',' or '...' before 'v'" on the first line. Is there anything I need to include to use __int64?

Comment: @Tech:  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Tech:  I have limited experience with GCC, but I found this which may be useful to you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=889612

Comment: @Tech:  If appropriate for your problem, you might also just use another native type that is more commonly supported, such as `unsigned long`.  It doesn't *have* to be `__int64`

Comment: @John:  Doesn't GCC use `long long` for 64-bit support?

Comment: @Zac:  I have no idea.  As I said, I have limited experience with GCC.

Comment: Just for reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523483/does-gcc-support-long-long-int

Answer (score 3):

The basic solution is to convert your 128-bit number to a (large) integer, then subsequently perform modulus and divide operations by 36.

However, if you're OK with wasting a couple of bits, why not convert to base 32 to make things easier? Then you can do everything with shifting and masking.

Comment: Another simple idea would be to use base64; it has several advantages: it's widespread (lots of tools to convert from/to it), is easily recognizable, and you can perform the conversion easily.

Comment: Base-64 is also very popular (uses digits, upper and lower-case letters, and a few punctuation like underscore and hyphen), and there are plenty of functions around to do that conversion.

Comment: @John Could you explain?  I was under the impression that one of the major strengths of Base64 is that it can in fact represent binary data in printable ASCII form.

Comment: @Abe: You are correct, bas64 *does* use only low-ascii printable characters.  I'll delete my previous comment.