# Integers greater than 4294967295 on 32-bit Windows

Tags: c++, integer

I'm trying to get to grips with C++ basics by building a simple arithmetic calculator application. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to make it capable of dealing with integers greater than 4294967295 on 32-bit Windows. I know that Windows' integrated Calculator is capable of this. What have I missed?

Note that this application should be compilable with both MSVC compiler and g++ (MinGW/GCC).

Thank you.

Comment: Look for `long long` and `long int` and `int64_t` on SO, perhaps?

Comment: If you want to make something similar to Calculator, you should be using `long double`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be both gcc and msvc compatible use <[stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h)>. It's source code compatible with both.

You probably want uint64_t for this. It will get you up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

There are also [libraries](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) to get you up to integers as large as you have memory to handle as well.

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++, that should be <cstdint>

Comment: @Steve: well, except that there is no `<cstdint>` in C++03. In implementations that don't provide it (MSVC prior to 2010, IIRC), you'll be reduced to dropping a platform-specific version of `stdint.h` into your project, in which case it won't be accessible via `#include <cstdint>`

Comment: Not available on mingw either. The implementation of cstdint I've seen just wraps a namespace around <stdint.h> anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use [__int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get 64-bit int calculations in Visual C++ - not sure if GCC will like this, though.

You could create a header file that typedefs (say) `MyInt64` to the appropriate thing for each compiler.  Then you can work internally with `MyInt64`, and the compiled code will be correct for each target.  This is a pretty standard way of supporting different target compilers on one source codebase.

afai can tell, `long long` would work OK for both, but I have not used GCC so YMMV - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523483/does-gcc-support-long-long-int) for GCC info and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx) for Visual C++.

Comment: C provides `<stdint.h>` and C++ provides `<cstdint>` for those `typedef`s. No reason to make your own.

Comment: @greyfade - yes, that's why I upvoted the current leading answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a "Large Number" class that would basically store the value across multiple variables in one form or another

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions, if 2^64 is big enough for you, you can use a 64 bit integer type (these are implementation dependent, so search for your particular compiler). On the other hand, if you want to be able to handle *any* number, you will have to use or implement a *BigInteger* type that encapsulates it. The implementation is an interesting exercise... basically use a vector of smaller type, operate on each subelement and then merge and normalize the result.